# Data security in result sets from Elastic Search, Solr or

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I need to add full-text search capabilities to my existing database. Of course first turn is to something like Solr or Elastic Search. And the blocking point I’ve got to is – how to securely display results returned from underlying search engine (let’s think about Solr or Elastic Search for now, however any other solution or engine that hit the point are also appreciated).

The tricky context is that I have, for example, in my system Personal Profile records that are to be indexed. One of the fields in personal profile is – manager’s feedback. Normally in the system that field is visible only to employee’s direct manager and higher hierarchy, i.e. ‘manager’ from another branch will not be able to see that field. However, I want that field to be searchable via full text search but only for people who actually can see it.

Now I query Solr for ‘stupid’ (that is query string) and it returns me N documents. When returning that to end-user I’ll remove the ‘Manager’s feedback’ field because end-user is not the manager of given people – but just presence of the document in resultset is already the evidence of ‘stupid’ guys …

The question is – what is workable approach to handle that use-case? Is it possible to plug into Solr/ES with home-grown security filter for outputs?

Caveats:

- filtering out only fields do not work because of above mentioned scenario
- filtering out complete documents will not work because of

  1. search engine does not tell which fields matched – therefore no way to manually filter resultset by field http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Best-way-to-return-which-field-matched-td2713071.html
  2. even this does work, removing documents from result set will spoil down facets (e.g. number of matches by department) returned by the engine – I’ll have to either recalculate facets manually or they will not match to manually filtered records and will reveal what I actually do not want to show to end users

Answer (score 1):

In Solr you can create [`multiValued`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Fields) fields. In your case you can use it to store de-normalized values of organization structure.

In described scenario you will create multi valued field `ouId` (Organization Unit Id) and store employee's ouId and all parent ouIds. In other words you will save *allowed* ouIds into this field.

In search scenario you will use [FilterQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) - `fq` parameter filtering by ouId of manager.

Example:

```
..&fq=ouId:12
```

where *12* is organization unit id of selected manager.

Comment: I did not mention, but this approach was evaluated already and declined because - number of ouIDs can be really large (in organization of 5000+ employees). This has to be done for each restrictable field (e.g. multiply by 10-20) - this gives overhead,  of ~50000 items and overcomplicates query to solr. And finally - this will be completely ruined when org-structure changes :( - all ACLs will have to be recalculated.

Comment: De-normalization has pros and cons. Overhead is * avg. organization structure depth. Your 20 means that some employees have 20 levels to the CEO. Even if this is true solr response times will be under 100ms (in our case with more than 800000 records average response time is around 50ms). If organization changes dramatically - you just re-index whole database (for 5000 employees this should take around 10-30 seconds).

Comment: I feel I’m missing something in your comments. ‘20’ in my case means each record (to be indexed) has 20 different fields each of which have own permissioning  rules – therefore ACL has to be assigned to each of these fields individually. I think I differently understand what is needed to be stored in ouId – in general this can be any dynamic rule that finally results in ‘allow’/’deny’ for each user in the company, therefore ACL will be really long if specified this way. Your solution addresses only one use-case of ACL assignment (granularity to org unit), which we cannot limit ourselves to :(.

Comment: From my experiences from HRM your requirements will not be effective, very hard to maintain and only few will realy use them.
On the other hand de-normalization is regular process in all search solutions and Solr is made for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is helpful for you https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-security-plugin It adds Document level security to elasticsearch.

"Currently for user based authentication and authorization Kerberos/SPNEGO and NTLM are supported through 3rd party library waffle (only on windows servers). For UNIX servers Kerberos/SPNEGO is supported through tomcat build in SPNEGO Valve (Works with any Kerberos implementation. For authorization either Active Directory and generic LDAP is supported). PKI/SSL client certificate authentication is also supported (CLIENT-CERT method). SSL/TLS is also supported without client authentication.

You can use this plugin also without Kerberos/NTLM/PKI but then only host based authentication is available.

As of now two security modules are implemented:

Actionpathfilter: Restrict actions against Elasticsearch on a coarse-grained level like who is allowed to to READ, WRITE or even ADMIN rest api calls
Document level security (dls): Restrict actions on document level like who is allowed to query for which fields within a document"